# Is "retval" good python style?

Tags: python, coding-style

Is there a strong reason to use a retval variable vs just returning a calculation?

```
def add(self, x, y):
    return x + y
```

versus

```
def add(self, x, y):
    retval = x + y
    return retval
```

I feel like I usually see retval (or some other named variable) in code examples but it seems like a (small) waste to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this example it won't make a difference but in longer functions it can be beneficial (for subjective reasons) to have one `result` or `retval` variable and only return that value at the end. This can make the code easier to understand (provided it is structured well) by only having one return location.

That being said, it depends on the developer's preferences and in some functions multiple return locations are equally readable.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to use it is when you want to use the value before you return it. for example, printing it before you return.

Comment: I disagree. If you have a fairly complicated conditional or some cleanup code, using `retval` instead of some arbitrary name for the variable can add clarity and reduce the chance of mistakes if the function is modified.

Comment: I accept your argument, thanks for writing it